# What is the right way to send file types from angular4 to asp.netcore?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, http, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using angular4.2 cli running on local//4200 and asp.netCore running Local//62567.

in my start up class in asp.net core I allowed :

```
//add cors service
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors",
                builder => {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
                 );
```

When I send my post request I get this:

```
:65223/api/Net:1 POST http://localhost:65223/api/Net 500 (Internal Server Error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:65223/api/Net. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Then I added the following header in my response:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*'
```

I enabled cors on my controller but I am new to javascript and using http to transfer files over apis. Im confused about what are the best methods to do this. Is it best to send a form or a binary array of bytes when it comes to working with binary types. How do two different languages know what exactly a file contains at any given time. Im going to post my code down below thank you for taking the time out of your day to read this.

### .Net

```
[EnableCors("Cors")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
{

     var uploader= Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");

     foreach (var file in files)
     {
         if (file.Length > 0)
         {
             using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploader, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
             {
                 await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
             }
          }
      }
      return Created(uploader, files);

}
```

### Angular4.2+

component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'new-upload',
    template: `


    <mat-card class="card">
    <mat-card-content>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="message.owner" placeholder="Name">
         </mat-form-field>

        <input type="file" name="file" (change)="getFiles($event)"> 


      <mat-card-actions>
        <button (click)="post()" mat-raised-button color="primary">POST</button> 
      </mat-card-actions> 

    </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>  

`
})


export class UploadComponent {

   constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) {}

   files : FileList; 

   getFiles(event){ 
       this.files = event.target.files; 
       this.message.img = event.target.files;//injected new file from server
   } 

   logForm(event) { 
        console.log(this.files); 
   } 

   message = {
       owner: '',
       img:FileList  //made new file list t
   }

   post() {
      this.uploadService.postMessages(this.message);
      console.log(this.message)
      console.log(this.message.text)
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are working with files, you have to encode your form values as `FormData` before posting them to server. Consider the following code for example,

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("files", this.files);

this.uploadService.post(formData).subscribe();
```

In MVC/Razor Pages, form attribute `enctype='multipart/form-data'` automatically encodes your form values to `FormData`. But in Angular/Ajax, you have to do the encoding part on your own and it will send the whole file over http (you don't have to convert it to binary type array).

The server only knows about the file only when you post it over http. Upon posting you can check different properties of the `IFormFile` (it basically represents the whole file) to know what exactly a file contains.

On client side, if you do want to know what exactly a file contains, you can use the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API to read the file contents.

Comment: Its saying its created but im not getting the physical file into the uploads folder. Is  there a way to pluck say an image file out of IFormFile.  Im honestly just getting depressed by this. it says its working but i dont see a file in my uploads folder

Comment: apparently chrome blocks Xmlhttprequests that originate at the same domain origin .  I was working on localhost on both the frontend - backend running on different ports and chrome puts options in the headers when it sees an event on the file upload.